# Checkout subdirectory of git repository

Tags: git, deployment, push, hook, git-checkout

I have set up push-to-deploy for git repo using post-receive hook and now I need somehow make it to checkout only content of a particular directory of repository, like below:

```
repo.git/dir1/dir11 -> /var/www/html/site1
repo.git/dir2       -> /var/www/html/site2
```

I want to have only contents of directory checked out, not full structure, so at the end I would have the following:

```
/var/www/html/site1/"whatever is in dir1/dir11/ directory".
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an index file for each target directory you want to maintain this way and use the low-level commands like read-tree directly.

```
# prefix the index paths with the repo's .git directory path
( export GIT_INDEX_FILE=site1.index
  export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/site1
  git read-tree -um `git write-tree` commit:dir1/dir11
)
( export GIT_INDEX_FILE=site2.index
  export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/site2
  git read-tree -um `git write-tree` commit:dir2
)
```

The two-tree `git read-tree -um` is the fundamentals of checkout, it assumes your index is derived from the first tree and transitions to the second as for checkout (or fast-forward merge, both do the same read-tree, but merge updates the current HEAD where checkout switches it; read-tree doesn't deal with refs at all). The write-tree will just spit the same tree you last read-tree'd, or the empty tree initially, unless you've been doing other things to the index.